# .htaccess, can I block all requests starting with exactly "/index.php?action="

Tags: .htaccess, filter

Is there a .htacces way to block all request starting with exactly `/index.php?action=`?

I figured out:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \baction=\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

But how do I put the part `/index.php?` in front of that pattern. I tried a lot, but it didn't work and only this part of the pattern also blocks &action= parameters somewhere else in a URL

Hope you can help. Many thanks in advance,
Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `THE_REQUEST` variable to match full URL and block it like this:

```sh
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?action= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: you are the best and quicker than lightning! SiteGround.com support couldn't help me with this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \baction=\b [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ - [F]
> ```
>
> But how do I put the part /index.php? in front of that pattern.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `^` in your example) matches the URL-path part of the URL (less the slash prefix). So, you can do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action= [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,F]
```

This matches any request that starts `/index.php?action=` (case-insensitive).

The regex you had initially (ie. `^`) is successful for everything, so would match any URL that starts `/<anything>?action=`.

The difference between this approach and checking against `THE_REQUEST` (as in @anubhava's answer) is that this will also block requests that have been internally rewritten to `/index.php?action=`, whereas `THE_REQUEST` will only block direct requests from the client.